# Bootstrap Validator - possible to conditionally call remote validator?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have what I believe to be a simple requirement but I can't figure out how to implement it.

I have a user registration form and the username field has a bunch of validation checks:

```
    fields: {
        username: {
            message: 'The username is not valid',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The username is required and cannot be empty'
                },
                stringLength: {
                    min: 6,
                    max: 30,
                    message: 'The username must be between 6 and 30 characters long'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/,
                    message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical and number'
                },
                different: {
                    field: 'password',
                    message: 'The username and password cannot be the same as each other'
                },
                remote: {
                    message: 'The username is not available',
                    url: '/api/username/valid',
                    type: 'GET'
                },
            }
        }
```

My remote validator checks that the username is not already taken. The problem is that the remote validator is called on every keypress along with the other validators. It actually only makes sense to call the remote validator once all the other validations on this field are true. Any ideas how to achieve that ?

Comment: Relates to #1021 [Run remote validation after other validations](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/issues/1021)

Answer (score 0):

Use

> trigger: 'blur'

See more here: http://bootstrapvalidator.com/settings/#field-trigger

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **Verbose** here. `verbose: false,`will cause all other validations to occur before the 'remote' will happen.

```
fields: {
    username: {
        verbose: false,
        message: 'The username is not valid',
        validators: {
            notEmpty: {
                message: 'The username is required and cannot be empty'
            },
            stringLength: {
                min: 6,
                max: 30,
                message: 'The username must be between 6 and 30 characters long'
            },
            regexp: {
                regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/,
                message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical and number'
            },
            different: {
                field: 'password',
                message: 'The username and password cannot be the same as each other'
            },
            remote: {
                message: 'The username is not available',
                url: '/api/username/valid',
                type: 'GET'
            },
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible doing like this can work .

```
   remote: {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'RegistrationEmailCheck',
                        delay: 1000,

                        message: 'Your Message'
                     }
```